# Serialize each reference of the same class differently in GSON/Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, gson

Let's say I have an object of class *A* that contains reference to object of class *B*, and a reference to object of class *C*. Object of class *B* contains reference to *C* too:

> ```
> A -> C         (1)
> A -> B -> C    (2)
> ```

I want to serialize an object of class *A* in such a way that it includes fields *c1* and *c2* from reference *(1)* and different fields, e.g. *c2* and *c3* from the reference *(2)*:

> ```
> A {
>    C {
>        c1: ...
>        c2: ...
>      },
>    B {
>        C {
>           c2: ...
>           c3: ...
>          }
>       }
>   }
> ```

Typically GSON or Jackson give possibility to exclude fields from all objects of specific class, that is always exclude for example *c1* and *c2* (in both references).

Is there any way to choose precisely which fields should be serialized and which not in GSON or Jackson?
Or if not, how to do it any other way (*manually*, without GSON/Jackson)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jackson's `@JsonSerialize` + `custom serializer`.

like this:

```
class A {

    @JsonSerialize(using = C1Serializer.class)
    C c;

    B b;
} 

class B {
    @JsonSerialize(using = C2Serializer.class)
    C c;
}

// you can do a lot of stuff in a custom serializer
class C1Serializer extends JsonSerializer<C> {

    static class FirstTwoFields {
        int c1
        int c2
        public FirstTwoFields(C c) {
            c1 = c.c1;
            c2 = c.c2;
        }

        //   getter and setters or delegate c's instead
        // .......
    }

    public void serialize(C c,
                      JsonGenerator jgen,
                      SerializerProvider provider){
        jgen.writeObject(new FirstTwoFields(c));
    }

}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, thanks! Just one more thing: What if I wanted to create two or more different ways to serialize the same field?  

For example: If I'm serializing object *A* I want to use *C2Serializer* indeed. However when I want to serialize *B* object on its own, I want to use yet another custom serializer, call it *C3Serializer*. Will it be sufficient to create for example different annotations for each of those references and check it in *serialize* method:

public void serialize(C c, ...) {  
    if (c has annotation A1) ...  
    ...  
    else if (c has annotation A2) ...  
}?

Comment: you can create many different `wrapper classes`, say `class WrapperA { B b; C c; }` then every Wrapper has its own custom serializer on B and C.

Comment: spring mvc 4.1 has @JsonView support, you might need a look.

Comment: I'm not using Spring in this project, but thanks anyway for the information. I've discovered also [flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net), which seems to be a good serializer to use in RESTful Services.